# Clear Case - Windows can't find 'Clearviewupdate'

Tags: clearcase

I'm trying to add a new stream, and once I set it up, and clear case attempts to begin downloading the files, I am presented with the following message.

Do any ClearCase Guru's out there have any idea why I would be getting this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is in the bin directory of your ClearCase installation (for instance: `C:\Rational\ClearCase\bin\clearviewupdate.exe`).
So it should be a simple `PATH` issue.

If Windows cannot find that exe, it shouldn't be able to find any other (`clearexplorer`, `clearprojexp`, `cleartool`, ...)

Comment: The only other cause could be some fie corruption... in which case: `sfc /scannow`

Comment: recently I went and changed the environment variable of PATH to something else (in order to work an IDE.) When I realized changing it affected clearcase, I changed it back. There's a good chance I didn't set it correctly. 
I'll fix this up, if it works, I'll mark as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding ..\ClearCase\bin which has the clearviewupdate.exe to PATH variable and restart Clearcase. It should work :)